# Internship application possibly rescinded

Tags: internship, rejection

I applied for an internship and went through phone interviews a few weeks ago.  I thought the phone interview went well, and at the end of it, the hiring manager asked me for a 2-page essay.  A few days later the hiring manager called me to for a few more questions and sounded certain that he wanted to hire me.

I then heard from the University talent partner a few days later and confirmed that I’ve been selected.  I got an email offer, accepted it, spoke regarding the next steps and was told I will hear from the on boarding team last week.  I didn’t hear from them but the talent partner sent me an email stating they’ve been having problems with the system.  The next day she followed up saying they’ve been able to fix it and that I should hear from them early this week.  I didn’t receive anything by Wed night so I sent her an email as per her instructions to follow up if this happens.  I didn’t get a reply from her but instead got an automated rejection letter — so I am confused.

Should I send another email?

Answer (score 7):

I'd email again. Perhaps even call if you have a number.

I would not assume the worst. It's possible something in the system was screwed up and in order to fix it they just deleted a bunch of open job postings, which triggered automatic rejection emails for anyone who had applied to them (ask me how I know...).

Comment: +1 for calling, given that they have already said they are having system problems I'd be assuming that this is a glitch as opposed to a genuine rejection unless someone confirmed otherwise over the phone or a direct e-mail. Plus if they are still having issues you can't rely on any sent e-mails actually reaching the correct person so they might not even know there is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the rejection letters are sent automatically if they click certain buttons in their tool. Try to get ahold of someone to confirm the rejection letter. Be nice about and don't draw conclusions.

> Hello Mr/Ms Whoever You Spoke to, I received a rejection letter. I am confused since last we spoke, you said I was hired. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt to send another email, especially since they've been having computer problems.

However, you might be better off if you can phone someone.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses!  I sent out an email asking whether this is an error or if the offer was rescinded.  I got a reply right away saying the hiring process is ongoing :). From what I understood I think they were indeed deleting the job posting which triggered that.